# How would I go about improving the efficiency (Scheme)?

Tags: scheme

I have this code:

```
(define tree `(A (B (C)) (D (E)) (C (E))))

(define (prog1 graph)
    (let ([seen `()])
      (define (sub g)
          (cond 
              [(member (car g) seen) `()]
              [else 
               (set! seen (cons (car g) seen))
               (cond
                 [(null? (cdr g)) (list (car g))]
                 [else
                  (cons (car g) (map sub (cdr g)))])])) 
    (delete `() (sub graph))))

(define delete
  (lambda (x y)
      (if (null? y )
            `()
      (if (eqv? (car y) x)
           (delete x (cdr y))
      (cons (car y) (delete x (cdr y)))))))
```

It prints a connected graph where all the nodes appear once.

Running `(prog1 tree)`

prints: `(A (B (C)) (D (E)))`

I have looked at various depth-first searches in lisp (something which is similar to what I'm trying to do) and they appear to be much more elegant to this, some using iterative approaches. I am aware that the program isn't very efficient (on huge trees it runs pretty slow) so how would I go about improving the efficiency of this code?

Thanks, James

Comment: Are you sure this function does exactly what you want?  For example,

    (prog1 '((a a a)))

gives

    ((a a a))

Comment: The nodes are unique and the graph cannot have loops. So (a a a) would not be a valid graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `member` procedure performs an `O(n)` lookup on lists every time it's invoked. That's not what we want for quickly testing set membership, for that you should use a data structure providing an `O(1)` complexity for both adding elements and testing element membership in a collection, ideally a Set data structure or in its place a Hash Table. For example, in Racket try replacing these lines (or use the default hash table implementation in your Scheme interpreter):

```
(let ([seen `()]) => (let ([seen (make-hash)])

[(member (car g) seen) `()] => [(hash-has-key? seen (car g)) '()]

(set! seen (cons (car g) seen)) => (hash-set! seen (car g) 'ok)
```

Also, in general you want to use [*quotes*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quote.html) in your code: `'()` instead of [*quasiquotes*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/qq.html): `` `() ``, see the links to understand the difference and when it's appropriate to use quasiquoting.

Finally, you can use the built-in `remove` procedure, there's no need to implement your own `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the bottleneck in this code will not be the tree traversal, but the `member` lookup.  The complexity of your function seems to be roughly O(M*N), where M is the number of distinct nodes and N is the number of total nodes.  The reason why M goes into this as a factor is because you're looking up nodes in a linear list, which takes time proportional to the length of the list (which in your case is proportional to the number of distinct nodes).

The way to get rid of the M is to use a more efficient data structure for the lookup.  R6RS defines hash tables, for instance.